# How to select one element from each sub-array of a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, combinations

So you are given only a single variable in python:

`array = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11] ]`

You want to be able to return a list of arrays containing only 1 element from each element of this `array`.

So in this case, our answer would be:

`ans = [[1, 4, 7, 10], [1, 4, 7, 11], [1, 4, 8, 10], [1, 4, 8, 11], [1, 4, 9, 10], [1, 4, 9, 11], [1, 5, 7, 10], [1, 5, 7, 11], [1, 5, 8, 10], [1, 5, 8, 11], [1, 5, 9, 10], [1, 5, 9, 11], [1, 6, 7, 10], [1, 6, 7, 11], [1, 6, 8, 10], [1, 6, 8, 11], [1, 6, 9, 10], [1, 6, 9, 11], [2, 4, 7, 10], [2, 4, 7, 11], [2, 4, 8, 10], [2, 4, 8, 11], [2, 4, 9, 10], [2, 4, 9, 11], [2, 5, 7, 10], [2, 5, 7, 11], [2, 5, 8, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [2, 5, 9, 10], [2, 5, 9, 11], [2, 6, 7, 10], [2, 6, 7, 11], [2, 6, 8, 10], [2, 6, 8, 11], [2, 6, 9, 10], [2, 6, 9, 11], [3, 4, 7, 10], [3, 4, 7, 11], [3, 4, 8, 10], [3, 4, 8, 11], [3, 4, 9, 10], [3, 4, 9, 11], [3, 5, 7, 10], [3, 5, 7, 11], [3, 5, 8, 10], [3, 5, 8, 11], [3, 5, 9, 10], [3, 5, 9, 11], [3, 6, 7, 10], [3, 6, 7, 11], [3, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 10], [3, 6, 9, 11]]`

I would like to place emphasis on the fact that you **do not** know the number of sub-arrays and the only input you get is the variable `array`.

I thought of writing a function that recursively calls itself to extract the elements from the arbitrary number of arrays but I couldn't get a logic for it.

How would one go about this problem?

I want to know the answer to this problem because it is part of a bigger question in which you need to select exactly **1** element from each array of the variable `array`, such that the difference in the **maximum** and the **minimum** values of the elements that are selected is overall **minimum**.

In the case of `array = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11] ]`, the answer would be **7**, which we get by selecting (3, 5, 8, 10) for example.

Is there an other way to approach this problem without having to generate all permutations of all elements?

Comment: Add your recursive function.

Comment: @shaikmoeed, I haven't got the logic for the recursive function. I was hoping that I could get some insight into it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```py
from itertools import product
array = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11] ]
result = list(product(*array))
print(result)
>>> [(1, 4, 7, 10), (1, 4, 7, 11), (1, 4, 8, 10), (1, 4, 8, 11), (1, 4, 9, 10), 
(1, 4, 9, 11), (1, 5, 7, 10), (1, 5, 7, 11), (1, 5, 8, 10), (1, 5, 8, 11), 
(1, 5, 9, 10), (1, 5, 9, 11), (1, 6, 7, 10), (1, 6, 7, 11), (1, 6, 8, 10), 
(1, 6, 8, 11), (1, 6, 9, 10), (1, 6, 9, 11), (2, 4, 7, 10), (2, 4, 7, 11), 
(2, 4, 8, 10), (2, 4, 8, 11), (2, 4, 9, 10), (2, 4, 9, 11), (2, 5, 7, 10), 
(2, 5, 7, 11), (2, 5, 8, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (2, 5, 9, 10), (2, 5, 9, 11), 
(2, 6, 7, 10), (2, 6, 7, 11), (2, 6, 8, 10), (2, 6, 8, 11), (2, 6, 9, 10), 
(2, 6, 9, 11), (3, 4, 7, 10), (3, 4, 7, 11), (3, 4, 8, 10), (3, 4, 8, 11), 
(3, 4, 9, 10), (3, 4, 9, 11), (3, 5, 7, 10), (3, 5, 7, 11), (3, 5, 8, 10), 
(3, 5, 8, 11), (3, 5, 9, 10), (3, 5, 9, 11), (3, 6, 7, 10), (3, 6, 7, 11), 
(3, 6, 8, 10), (3, 6, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 10), (3, 6, 9, 11)]
```